# How to write the Text on Image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I have a sample code as below:

```
def DrawMTF(img, edges, perm, mtfs, crop_ratio, color_map_range):
  """Draws the result of the image sharpness test on the test image."""
  # Map MTF values to hue values.
  hues = ((mtfs - color_map_range[0]) /
          (color_map_range[1] - color_map_range[0])) / 3.0
  np.clip(hues, 0.0, 1.0/3, out=hues)

  # Draw the edges.
  for idx, edge_id in enumerate(perm):
    edge = edges[edge_id]
    start = (1 - crop_ratio) * edge[0:2] + crop_ratio * edge[2:4]
    end = crop_ratio * edge[0:2] + (1 - crop_ratio) * edge[2:4]
    cv2.line(img, _FtoI(tuple(_Up(start))), _FtoI(tuple(_Up(end))),
         _HSVToBGR(hues[idx], 1.0, 1.0), thickness=2,
         shift=_UPSAMPLING_BITS, lineType=cv2.CV_AA)
```

The output image as below

[image]

my questions are "how could I write the mtf values near the edges?"
I used the API "cv2.putText", but I didn't know the position and couldn't transfer the type of mtf value to "%.3f".

How could I do?

Comment: If you can draw the line, you must know the position. Am I right?

Comment: '(img, format(mtfs[idx],'.3f'), _FtoI(tuple(_Up(start)-(_Up(end)))),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (225,0,0))'. The position didn't change, and the mtfs[idx] value overlap. How can I do?

Comment: Glad to hear that, sorry for not responding to your comment, I'm really busy and I simply forgot to do it!